# Confused result of changing the bst-file for bibliography in Russian

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

The present question is the continuation of the previous discussion ([See here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327378/bibtex-style-settings-needed)).

I've tried to change BiBTeX style for needed purpose by two ways: using `custom-bib` and by modification of `plainnat.bst` file (thanks to Mico's suggestion). Both times I got the same result:
[image]

That is, initials before points were lost. I'm sure, that the issue is caused by necessity to use specified options for precessing BiBTeX-file in Russian. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please don't show us just a screenshot of the problematic output. What we really need to see, in order to be able to offer a diagnosis, is the code that gives rise to the problematic output. Please prepare a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001), including a couple of bib entries.

Comment: OK. The code with problematic output can be downloaded from: [here](https://yadi.sk/d/P9AZFeVnuihfC)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the missing-characters business you're encountering is related to BibTeX, at least not directly. I downloaded the files you posted off-site and have had a look. I'm very sorry my Russian -- and even my ability to read text that uses Cyrillic letters -- isn't all that good. The following is therefore mainly going to be a set of suggestions, which you may want to treat as no more than a starting point for further investigations.

- Since your files are utf8-encoded, I strongly recommend you use a TeX engine that's fully utf8-enabled. I suggest you use LuaLaTeX. (I assume you've been using pdfLaTeX so far. Is that correct?) If you choose this route, you should comment out (or simply delete) the instructions `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` from the preamble of the main tex file. In their place, (a) insert the instruction `\usepackage{fontspec}` and (b) choose a font (via a `\setmainfont` instruction) that's on your system and has excellent support for Cyrillic characters. On my system (MacOSX 10.11.6; MacTeX2016), I found "Garamond Premier Pro"; I thus wrote `\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}` in the preamble. I trust you'll have several good fonts to choose from on your system.
- Run LuaLaTeX once.
- Next, instead of running "basic" BibTeX, which can probably handle only ASCII-encoded material without generating meaningless error messages, consider running `bibtexu`, which is utf8-enabled. You will probably need to open a command window, switch to the directory that contains your main tex file (`SampleFile.tex`, say), and type

  ```
  bibtexu SampleFile
  ```

  Ignore any cryptic error messages.
- Then, run LuaLaTeX twice more to generate both the formatted bibliography and citation call-outs.

I get the following output from this exercise; is this roughly what it should look like?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% I've shrunk your tex file down to the absolute minimum...
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro} 
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-re}
\begin{document}
Citations: \citep{Ajn1962, AbrAru1963, Bab1984, AlbN1972}
\bibliography{sample_bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I use a **dvi** previewer for TeX compilation. As use of `bibtexu` is not recommended by the most of experts (I consulted at a number of sites), I apply the following workaround [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183724/cyrillic-first-names-problem-with-natbib-and-bibtex). And it does work!
In any case, I appreciate you for valuable tips.

Comment: @Konstantin - Glad my suggestion was at least somewhat useful, and glad you found the other posting, in which egreg suggested a work-around for cyrillic-alphabet initials. (You might end up doing a lot of recoding of first initials, though...) About `bibtexu`: its usability and stability appear to depend importantly on how many bytes are used to encode a given utf8 character. Cyrillic-alphabet characters are mostly (exclusively?) encoded using 2 bytes per character, and `bibtexu` seems to be fine with those. Finally, do feel free to upvote and/or accept my answers. ;-)

Comment: @Konstantin - About the use of a dvi previewer: I understand that's an issue that's separate from the engine and format used to compile the files. To create a dvi file rather than a pdf file with LuaLaTeX, type `lualatex --output-format=dvi <tex-file>` at a command line. Alternatively, configure your front-end so that the string `--output-format=dvi` when running LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you. 

It is very simple to do so in my bundle `MiKTeX+WinEdt`.

_Regards_